# Protected методы в Python

Tags: python, ооп

Как я понял, в Python, `protected` значение объявляется одним `_` вначале, а `private` двумя -  `__`. Не понятно то, зачем питон выводит `protected` значение, ведь оно должно быть доступно только у себя и у наследуемых классов, не?

```
class Make():
    _foo = "Protect <--";

    def fun():
       pass

class MakeTwo(Make):

    def off(self):
       print(self._foo);


t = Make();
print t._foo; # Protect <--
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Дело в том, что в Python по факту нет ни private, ни protected полей в классах. Использование знака подчёркивания лишь сообщает пользователям кода о том, что использовать это поле вне класса не стоит, но доступ всё равно имеется.

> It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

Так называемые private поля на самом деле тоже доступны снаружи класса. Если используется имя поля `A.__field`, то (в CPython), если у нас есть экземпляр этого класса `a`, к этому полю `__field` можно будет обратиться следующим образом: `a._A__field`.

[Документация по классам: приватные поля](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)